# PHP: CURL result into array. Stop after A-Z values in array, disregard what follows

Tags: php, arrays, curl

After CURL'ing a page and creating a list of items in an array. I have no control over the markup. I'm trying to filter out the last remainder of items that don't follow the alphabet after the letter Z.

In this case I'd like to disregard indexes 7 and beyond.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Apple
    [1] => Acorn
    [2] => Banana
    [3] => Cucumber
    [4] => Date
    [5] => Zombify
    [6] => Zoo // last item
    [7] => Umbrella // disregard
    [8] => Kangaroo // disregard
    [9] => Apple // disregard
    [10] => Star // disregard
    [11] => Umbrella // disregard
    [12] => Kangaroo // disregard
    [13] => Apple // disregard
)
```

What I cannot figure out is the appropriate solution for the cutoff point at the letter Z.

```
$letters = range('A', 'Z');

foreach($listContent as $listItem) {
    foreach($letters as $letter) {
        if (substr($listItem, 0, 1) == $letter) {
            $newArray[] = $listItem;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at my answer below to see how you can avoid the inner foreach loop. I would also recommend to stick to one variable naming scheme, either use `$newArray`, `$listContent` (camelCase) or `$new_array`, `$listContent`.

Comment: Thanks SaschaM78. I updated my array example to more clearly demonstrate what I am after, and if it's possible. See my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will handle the updated array you posted.  For instance, it will keep Zombie and Zoo, but then it will end.

```
$letters = range('A', 'Z');
$newArray = array();

    foreach ($listContent as $listItem) {

        $firstLetter = substr($listItem, 0, 1);

        if (!in_array($firstLetter, $letters)) {
            break; // edited to break instead of continue.
        }

        $position = array_search($firstLetter, $letters);
        $letters = array_slice($letters, $position);

        $newArray[] = $listItem;
    }
```

Comment: Joe! Great simple example with minimal conditioning. This did the trick! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
$last= "A";
foreach($listContent as $listItem) {
  $current = strtoupper(substr($listItem, 0,1));

  // only add the element if it is alphabetically sorted behind the last element and is a character
  if ($current < $last || $current < 'A' || $current > 'Z') break;
  $last = $current;
  $newArray[] = $listItem;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. It's my fault for not specifying that after the letter Z, any first letter may follow. The value could be 'Star'.

Comment: @user1020989 glad you found a solution that worked for you and thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Have tested this and works correctly - to my understanding of your requirement:

```
$letters = range('A', 'Z');
$item_prev_char = "";

foreach( $listContent as $listItem ) 
{
    $item_first_char = substr($listItem, 0, 1);

    if ( $item_prev_char <= $item_first_char )
    {
    foreach( $letters as $letter ) 
        {
            if ($item_first_char == $letter ) 
            {
            $new_array[] = $listItem;
            $item_prev_char = $item_first_char;
            echo $listItem."<br/>";
            break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Chris. This is close. However it doesn't work if I have multiple first character listings with the same first letter. i.e. Apple, Acorn. Acorn would be removed.

Comment: Thanks Chris! This works. I resorted to using Joe42's answer since there were less conditions involved. Thanks for the help!